# Hook message loop in Windows Forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to hook the message loop in a Windows Forms application to do some tick-count related work.

I'm developing a tcp server using async methods (async/await) and I'm avoiding dealing with race conditions in a multi-threaded process - this is basically the reason I'm using async/await instead of other models. Because of this restriction, I can't create a background thread to do the tick-counting because with this I will end up in a multi-threaded code.

An option I thought was to somehow hook up the message loop in the Windows Forms, so I could easily do my tick-count related stuff using the same thread of my Windows Forms object, although I didn't find any suitable method or event in the Windows.Forms.Application class.

Anyone knows a way to do what I need?

Thanks.

Comment: Async/await is multithreading...

Comment: Hello. @GlenThomas. I know async/await is multi-threading, but the multi-threading in this model runs only in a lower-level layer. All code I write in the UI thread, using async/await, will be executed in the UI thread.

Comment: The async code won't be run in the UI thread

Comment: I know, this is what I meant... The async code will be executed in a system's thread-pooled thread, but when the async code ends it returns the execution to the caller thread, which in my case is the UI thread.

Comment: Yes you can achieve the same with any other type of .NET threading

Comment: What I want is just a way to execute tick-count dependent code without executing these code in a different thread. Any thoughts?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110063/discussion-between-ptr0x-and-glen-thomas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best approach may be to use a timer, which will execute your code on a timed interval:

```
var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
aTimer.Interval = 5000;
aTimer.Enabled = true;



// What you want to happen when the Elapsed event is raised.
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Just an addendum: if you need the Timer's callback to be executed in a specific SynchronizationContext, set the Timer.SynchronizingObject!

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want to override the message loop. That was a pretty common approach in much more primitive GUI solutions, but it is literally a last resort on .NET.

Since you just want a regular "tick", the most appropriate solution is a timer. Since you want it to run on the UI thread, you should use [`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Hello Stephen! I end up using the System.Timers.Timer because I need to declare this timer in a assembly which don't have any dependencies of the "ui layer". Also this timer I'm using have the possibility to run the callback in a specific synchronization context.